# How to append extra value to an array in class from another file using Extension swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have class in a file name MyClass.swift

```
class MyClass  {

    var arrayOfString : [String] = []

}
```

I need my team to append strings in this array when needed without modifying in the same file (before runtime) so if there is any way to do this use extension and modify in this array class for example to make a new file called NewClass.swift?

```
extension MyClass  {

  arrayOfString = ["New Value"]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you wish to have different array initialisers in different files which are combined *at compile time* into a single initialiser, that is using your example convert:

```
class MyClass  {
   var arrayOfString : [String] = []
}
```

and:

```
extension MyClass  {
   arrayOfString = ["New Value"]
}
```

into:

```
class MyClass  {
   var arrayOfString : [String] = ["New Value"]
}
```

and:

```
extension MyClass  {
   // arrayOfString = ["New Value"]
}
```

or something equivalent to that.

I do not believe the Swift language supports that. However Xcode is can help you here, it has two facilities you can use to construct a solution:

*Build Phases - Run Script*

In your Project's Settings there is an entry "Build Phases" which defines the set of operations Xcode goes through in building your project. The default set is: Target Dependencies, Compile Sources, Link Binary With Libraries and Copy Bundle Resources. The list is processed in order, top to bottom.

You may add other phases including a "Run Script" one which runs a script you write, which could be a shell script, Python code, Ruby code, etc. etc. The phase can optional take specified input files and produce output files.

Xcode provides a temporary build products directory into which you can write output files, any output files are subject to further processing by Xcode.

*Build Rules*

Also in your Project's Settings there is an entry "Build Rules" which defines how Xcode handles different file types. This allows you to introduce new file extensions which you then process to produce a new file with a known extension in the temporary products directory which Xcode will then further process. For example, you could write files with a `.ourSwift` extension which a processed by a script you provide into `.swift` files.

*What could you do with these?*

Well you could write a script which scans the project's source files, extracts the distributed parts of the initialiser, combines them and writes them into an existing or new file. The design of this and what you implement it in is totally up to you. For example, if you have your team indicate what they need to add to the initialiser by a special comment you might be able to use a simple combination of `grep` and `sed` to achieve your goal. Apple used to publish a more involved example of processing `.strings` files using a Ruby script which you might still be able to find in the dusty corners of the internet.

Xcode's documentation for these features won't win any prizes but that is your primary source; go read, explore, trial and you'll probably quickly have a solution that meets your needs.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I think is an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to the extension class and ask your team to add the data there.

```
extension MyClass  {
func addDataHere() {
    arrayOfString = ["New Value"]

    //ASK THEM TO ADD DATA
    arrayOfString.append("ONE")
    arrayOfString.append("TWO")
}
}
```

Try this, if you are looking for the same.

Comment: Then I should call this func in runtime I need to added compile time because I am doing some process in arrayOfString once the MyClass is init and I do not want that we all edit in the same file

Answer (score 0):

extention Myclass {

arrayofstirng.append("your value")

}